# WebTokenRequest and OneDriveClient

Tags: c#, onedrive

I'm trying to implement Onedrive client login by using [Connect to identity providers with Web Account Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager)

With this method finally I get a token using this code

```
private static async Task<string> RequestTokenAndSaveAccount(WebAccountProvider Provider, String Scope, String ClientID)
    {
        try
        {
            WebTokenRequest webTokenRequest = new WebTokenRequest(Provider, "wl.signin onedrive.appfolder onedrive.readwrite", ClientID);

            WebTokenRequestResult webTokenRequestResult = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(webTokenRequest);

            if (webTokenRequestResult.ResponseStatus == WebTokenRequestStatus.Success)
            {
                App.settings.onedriveStoredAccountKey = webTokenRequestResult.ResponseData[0].WebAccount.Id;

                return webTokenRequestResult.ResponseData[0].Token;
            }

            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

            return "";
        }
    }
```

But I can't use the returned token to create a OnedriveClient because I need a MsaAuthenticationProvider to create the client and it creates its own token ignoring the one coming from the WebTokenRequest, and it doesn't have any method to take the prior token.

There is a way to create a OneDriveClient without going to REST Onedrive API?

Thank you

**Edit:**

As there are (at this time) two main versions of OneDriveSDK and those are different from each other, there are two ways to achieve this.

**OneDrive.SDK 1.x**

As @Brad said, an `IAuthenticationProvider` is needed to create the `OneDriveClient`.

I got the solution from https://github.com/ginach/Simple-IAuthenticationProvider-sample-for-OneDrive-SDK.

I took the `SimpleAuthenticationProvider` into my code, and then created the client like this

```
var client = new OneDriveClient(
        new AppConfig(),
        /* credentialCache */ null,
        new Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.HttpProvider(),
        new ServiceInfoProvider(new SimpleAuthenticationProvider { CurrentAccountSession = new Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.AccountSession { accessToken = AccessToken } }),
         ClientType.Consumer);

    client.BaseUrl = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0";

    await client.AuthenticateAsync();
```

Where the accessToken is taken from the `RequestTokenAndSaveAccount` method.

**OneDrive.SDK 2.x**

For this case, the answer given by @dabox is the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to Brad's answer, you can create a new AuthenticationProivder implements the IAuthenticationProivder interface in the package `Microsoft.Graph.Core`. And there also is a `DelegateAuthenticationProvider` in package `Microsoft.Graph.Core` which provides a Delegate interface for you. An example looks like:

```
OneDriveClient oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(
new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
    async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        string accessToken = await GetAccessTokenSomeWhereAsync();

        // Append the access token to the request.
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
    }));
return oneDriveClient ;
```

Modified based on the Microsoft Graph's asp .net example: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample/blob/master/Microsoft%20Graph%20SDK%20ASPNET%20Connect/Microsoft%20Graph%20SDK%20ASPNET%20Connect/Helpers/SDKHelper.cs#L18

Comment: Hi, this is not valid because OneDriveClient is pretty different from GraphServiceClient which is the object refered in the documentation. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Edit, this is not valid for implementations of OneDrive.SDK 1.x. For OneDrive.SDK 2.x is working perfectly. @Brad answer is valid for OneDrive.SDK 1.x. I will edit my question to show how must be done for the two versions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`OneDriveClient` only requires an `IAuthenticationProvider`, which is a pretty simplistic interface. You can create your own and implement `AuthenticateRequestAsync` such that it calls your `RequestTokenAndSaveAccount` and then adds the bearer token to the request.